# Why .find() does not works if it work on global variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code:

```
/**
     * Fetch all restaurants.
     */
    static fetchRestaurants(callback) {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', DBHelper.DATABASE_URL);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status === 200) { // Got a success response from server!
                const json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                const restaurants = json.restaurants;
                callback(null, restaurants);
            } else { // Oops!. Got an error from server.
                const error = (`Request failed. Returned status of ${xhr.status}`);
                callback(error, null);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

   /**
     * Fetch a restaurant by its ID.
     */
    static fetchRestaurantById(id, callback) {
        // fetch all restaurants with proper error handling.
        DBHelper.fetchRestaurants((error, restaurants) => {
            if (error) {
                callback(error, null);
            } else {
                console.log(restaurants); //restaurants exists
                const restaurant = restaurants.find(r => r.id === 1); 
                console.log(restaurant); //restaurant is undefined
                window.teszt = restaurants; //for tests
                if (restaurant) { // Got the restaurant
                    callback(null, restaurant);
                } else { // Restaurant does not exist in the database
                    callback('Restaurant does not exist', null);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

When I run same `.find(r => r.id === 1)` on teszt, it works. Code also works if I grab simply desired item in array `const restaurant = restaurants[id-1]` and it's not undefined. But I should really prefer .find in case json structure will change.

Here is part of restaurants.json this is same as restaurants variable https://pastebin.com/tVLyUTVH

Logged out `JSON.stringify(restaurants)` also seems to be normal.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Mission Chinese Food","neighborhood":"Manhattan","photograph":"1.jpg"," ...
```

Comment: can you show a small example of `restaurants` structure - my guess is that `id` isn't what you think it is (perhaps it's a `"1"` rather than a `1`)

Comment: Can you post the code of `DBHelper.fetchRestaurants`?

Comment: @JaromandaX I've updated post.

Comment: @Bergi I can, but if restaurants variable exists, problem propabaly is not there.

Comment: Please give us enough of a sample within the question itself for it to be answerable. Specifically the output of the `console.log` call would help.

Comment: @Zydnar The array might exist, but it might not yet be filled. Also try `console.log(JSON.stringify(restaurants))` instead of `console.log(restaurants)`.

Comment: @Bergi - it'd be unusual for a callback `fetchRestaurants((error, restaurants) => {` to call before restaurants is fully populated!! of course, the code for `fetchRestaurants` would clarify that :p

Comment: @JaromandaX updated

Comment: @JaromandaX Unusual, and wrong, for sure, but it would have explained the error. (Don't see a mistake in the posted code, though).

Comment: @Bergi code from JSON.stringify looks normal `[{"id":1,"name":"Mission Chinese Food","neighborhood":"Manhattan","photograph":"1.jpg","` ...

Comment: there's something odd going on, that's for sure

Comment: @Zydnar With that data, the `find` should definitely work

Comment: I found something - problem occurs only using chrome canary.

Comment: I think it is solved - it looks like chrome canary bug.

Comment: @Zydnar Did you report it? Can you link the issue?

Comment: I just did via report issue in chrome menu, I've also submited transpilled file and lik to this post.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was only in chrome canary - so it looked like chrome canary bug. No idea why, but after restart same code worked. It propably was a memory leak. When after now all works again I can't provide any useful tests.

Comment: Would be good if you could narrow it down and produce a clear test case and perhaps an explanation for the bug…

Comment: Ok, I'll do it.